# cryptdisks_start: precheck failed: the device contains a filesystem type crypto_LUKS

Tags: gnome3, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I'm trying to use `cryptdisks_start` to open a LUKS device that is defined in my `/etc/crypttab`. Unfortunately, the command fails with the following error message:

```
martin ~ # cryptdisks_start luks-01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155
 * Starting crypto disk...
 * luks-01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155 (starting)..
 * luks-01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155: the precheck for '/dev/disk/by-uuid/01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155' failed:  - The device /dev/disk/by-uuid/01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155 contains a filesystem type crypto_LUKS.
 * luks-01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155 (failed)...
   ...fail!
```

A rather strange error, because of course that device has to contain a `crypto_LUKS` filesystem!

The relevant line from `/etc/crypttab`, as set up by GNOME Disks:

```
luks-01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155 UUID=01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155 /etc/luks-keys/luks-01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155 nofail
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `/etc/crypttab` line is missing the option keyword `luks`. Changing the line to this resolved the issue:

```
luks-01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155 UUID=01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155 /etc/luks-keys/luks-01a2e5d8-9211-40ce-b160-d3f973d1a155 luks,nofail
```

This is due to the fact that `cryptdisks_start` uses the options to determine what kind of encryption is being used so that it will use the correct command to open the device. Without the `luks` option, `cryptdisks_start` will try to open the device as a plain dm-crypt device with `cryptsetup create`. Luckily a sanity check prevents this, although it causes a confusing error message.

Apparently the Disks tool of GNOME3 writes this incorrect line to `/etc/crypttab` when using the unlock icon and saving the passphrase.